How can I render hair particle system as cylinders?
How can I render hair particle system as cylinders? As solid objects that have thickness?

if you use the classical hair particle system (and not geonodes), go into the Particles panel > Render > Render As > choose Object and then Object > Instance Objct > select the object

But I want the cylinders to be curved. And being able to control the curvature.

Maybe you should tell us exactly what you want in the question, not in the comments and only when someone presents something that does not work for you...

if you choose an object as particle you won't be able to curve each particle as if it was path hair, unless you apply the particle system in the modifier panel, it will make the instances real and editable through Sculpt mode for example, but maybe tell a bit more about what you want to achieve?

Gordon I am really tired of you complaining about every post I make here. Last time you told me that I completely changed all the basic funtions of Blender. Seriously? If my questions are not up to your standard, do not answer them.

@mts10 If you put more details in your questions you might not get so many complaints or requests for more information We can't guess what you are thinking! https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

I posted while I was working and elaborated in the comments. Thanks @moonboots for the help.

Gordon was right though, you need to give more details  ;)

I did and I got the answer I needed.

@mts10 Don't worry, I will no longer bother you or try to answer your questions. But I'm not the only one asking asking you for more details in the past and on the other hand you are not the one to reward answers very often anyway.
